# Build Project using Cmake and Wxwidget

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, wxwidgets

I can't build my project using Cmake nad visual 11. It give this error :

```
CMake Error at C:/Cmake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Cmake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Cmake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:832 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)Framework/FrameworkGUI/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: Is wxWidgets installed? *Where* is it installed? If it's in a non-standard location, try adding that to `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`. Note that you'll need the libraries *and* the headers.

Comment: Yes It's installed to a non-standard location. I have the libraries and the headers, so that is good. But i dont now where should i add -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=

Comment: You should add that as an argument to cmake when you create your VS project. Assuming you're creating your project in a subdirectory of your actual project, it should look something like cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 2011" .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<your_path>

Comment: You could also be using one of the GUIs... but generally speaking going command line is better (because it allows automating the build process).

Comment: Either i did not that well or it's not working. I'm new to Cmake and wxwidget, so i think it's the first option. can you be more specific.

Comment: Her is a screenshot of what i have                                                   http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/710483611.png

Comment: You'll need to post you CMakeLists.txt file(s). Something is going wrong with your treatment of find_package( wxWidgets ). Clearly CMake is telling you it's not found even though some of the variables are populated. I would also look at the advanced settings in CMake, the missing variable might be hidden there. Finally, once you configure the first time, your missing variable(s) should be highlighted for you, since you use the gui.

Comment: Change your WxWidgets default directory, before calling to `FIND_PACKAGE(..)`, writing `SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR <your_wxWidgets Directory>)`

Comment: @fenix688: No, that would make your `CMakeLists.txt` depending on your private setup. The idea is to keep CMakeLists.txt *generic*, and have any *specific* settings on the command line. But you bring up a point: **wxWidgets does want its non-standard path in `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR`, not `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Judging from the screenshot however, that is correctly set already. Ben, what does `C:\lib\wxwidget` look like? And, in `C:/Cmake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake`, find the `DBG_MSG` macros (line ~175) and uncomment them for debug output. Post that as well, please.

Comment: I fixed the problem. It was in fact that Cmake Gui did not detect all the wxwidget lib that i want to use. I give it the path of this lib and it worked.